# In Rails, Using Mongoid, How do I find all Models with a valid (not nil) has_one reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, has-one

So I have a two models like this

```
class ModelParent
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  has_one :model_child
end

class ModelChild
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  belongs_to :model_parent
end
```

Assuming I have an persisted instance of ModelParent called mp in the rails console

```
mc = mp.create_model_child(:name=>"child")
```

and then do

```
mp.model_child
```

it returns a valid object

however if I search for it like this:

```
ModelParent.where(:model_child.ne => nil).length
```

it returns 0

I've tried creating model_child and then assigning it, also using build_model_child(), and each method shows model_child is clearly in the parent, however the query for not nil (.ne) fails to find all ModelParents with children.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

Answering my own question. I'm still unsure why the :model_child.ne => nil is not working, however...

I solved the problem by coding something like this:

```
  def self.with_child
    user_ids = ModelChild.all.only(:model_parent_id).map(&:model_parent_id)
    return ModelParent.where(:_id.in => user_ids).all
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not working as foreign key is stored on belongs to side of the relationship. So, in your case `ModelChild` collection will have a field `model_parent_id` and not the other way around. I guess you had already figured that out, but instead of solving it the way you did, I would suggest you switch around the `has_one` and `belongs_to` associations and then use:

```
 ModelParent.where(:model_child_id.ne => nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way, but I don't know if is more efficient or less: you can use the reject method.
For example:

```
ModelParent.all.reject{ |r| r.model_child.nil?}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on the .ne in such cases, I found that .ne method isn't always working good:
For example try to put a string named "false" and try to search for it with .ne ;-)

I found out that for such cases the best way to find the proper models reliably is to filter by native Mongo **`$type`**

```
ModelParent.where(:model_child_id => { :$type => 7 })
```

Below the list of known types, found this much more efficient to find malformed fields

- Double 1
- String 2
- Object 3
- Array 4
- Binary data 5
- Undefined (deprecated) 6
- **Object id 7**
- Boolean 8
- Date 9
- Null 10
- Regular Expression 11
- JavaScript 13
- Symbol 14
- JavaScript (with scope) 15
- 32-bit integer 16
- Timestamp 17
- 64-bit integer 18
- Min key 255
- Max key 127